# All array slots contains last result

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda

Im pretty sure this has been asked before but I dont know what to search for:

I want to populate an array with what I've found in a lambda expression.
I do this

```
IEnumerable<CapOrderTimeSlot>[] dummyDates = new IEnumerable<CapOrderTimeSlot>[DayCount];

for (int i=0; i< DayCount; i++)
{
    dummyDates[i] = OrderSlots.Where(os => os.ComputedStartDate == FirstDate.AddDays(i));
}
```

The problem is that every item in the array ends up containing the same items (propably the last result in the loop).

How do I avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean by "_propably_ the last result in the loop"? How can you not be sure whether it is the last result? It either is or it isn't.

Comment: [here is a little explanation to what closure actually means](https://www.simplethread.com/c-closures-explained/)

Comment: did you chose `IEnumerable` on purpose? is it intended that the query is performed each time you access elements in `dummyDates`? Do you intend to change `OrderSlots`? so that you can react to changes dynamically during runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that this code saves expression in each array element, not a "materialized" collection. At the same time, all saved expressions are "linked" to the same value of i due to closure. That is why you are getting the last value.

Just change it this way:

```
for (int i=0; i< DayCount; i++)
{
    dummyDates[i] = OrderSlots.Where(os => os.ComputedStartDate == FirstDate.AddDays(i)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: might be better with a .Single and not ToArray at the end .. but that's up to the OP

Comment: @TonyAbrams why `Single`? the post shows `IEnumerable<CapOrderTimeSlot>[]` it needs an array of collections

Comment: @Mong Zhu ... whoops totally missed that :)

Comment: The result won't be the same in case later dummyDates array is traversed multiple times. If you leave expressions in the array, they will be executed over and over - may hurt performance and give some side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop variable `i` is captured by `Linq` method. Try to assign it to a local variable inside loop:

```cs
IEnumerable<CapOrderTimeSlot>[] dummyDates = new IEnumerable<CapOrderTimeSlot>[DayCount];

for (int i = 0; i < DayCount; i++)
{
    int temp = i;
    dummyDates[i] = OrderSlots.Where(os => os.ComputedStartDate == FirstDate.AddDays(temp));
}
```

[There](https://medium.com/@unicorn_dev/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-d169aa161aa6) is a nice article explaining this problem

Comment: how is this any different from just using the i?

Comment: i variable is captured and evaluated after linq execution. In case of local variable inside loop it'll be evaluated every time